# Centering an element in a div

Tags: css

I am trying to center a notification message within a div and i tried `top:50%` but its not working.I tried to put in some padding i don't like that method.You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VPdmT/

```
.message > .inner { 
    padding:22px 0 0 40px; 
    top:50%;
    margin:0 0 22px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 17px;
}
```

Comment: If the .inner DIV has some fixed height & width you can do it like this, http://jsfiddle.net/VPdmT/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.message > .inner {
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:0 17px;
    display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.message.success {
    color:#0e6200;
    background-color:#d8ffcc;
    border-color:#b3f39f !important;
    display: table;
}
```

The important part is that div with `table-cell` display must be inside div with `table` display.

Comment: This too has worked:margin: 10px 0 0 22px;
 padding:4px 0 4px;
 padding-left:10px; I am working on the shorthand properties for that.

Answer (score 1):

The top CSS rule can only be applied to element's whose position is anything other than static. Because you have not declared absolute or relative, then top is ignored.

**EDIT:** On to the real answer, do this:

```
.message { display: table; width: 100%; }
.message>.inner { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.message > .inner { 
    padding:22px 0 0 40px; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0 0 22px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 17px;
}
```